# Capistrano 2 deploy:rollback task clarification

Tags: capistrano, chef-infra

1. which file is referenced by Capistrano 2 to perform a rollback?

I am using chef's `deploy_revision` and this create a cache of the revisions under

```
/var/chef/cache/revision-deploys/path/to/myapp
```

I was testing Capistrano 2 in the same project, trying to figure out which one i choose for the deployment. i did this to perform a rollback

```
cap <stagename> deploy:rollback
```

but it ended up rolling back to a revision which is not in line with the one in the cache cache copy of the revision list.

I may be wrong to expect Capistrano to follow what was there for the chef. But i am trying to straighten this rollback in Cap2.

2. the application service fails to start properly

Inside the deploy.rb file, i placed a task like this

```
after "deploy", "deploy:restart_app"
```

the task looks like this:

```
task :restart_app, :roles => :web do
    run "sudo /etc/init.d/abc restart", :shell => :bash
  end
```

but when the deploy is completed if do a status for my app (abc), it says "process dead and pid exist". this also true the pid file exist in `/var/run/abc.pid`

manual test execution of `sudo /etc/init.d/abc restart` as the deploy user, work fine.

Comment: Chef deploy is inspired by capistrano, but has no link to it. I would be surprised they're really compatible. For the Second question, show your recipe code if you wish a feedback (is the user define in the resource ? what environemnt do you pass ?).

Comment: @Tensibai : the 2nd question appears to be an issue in my code for the app. i am going to review that first. Any idea on what Capistrano 2 looks up to, to determine the last revision to be rolled back to when 'cap <stage> deploy:rollback' is executed

Comment: Sorry I'm not using capistrano and I've no knowledge on it.

Comment: This is what i learnt so far from the cap community, it does a ll -t (sorts) the folders inside the 'deploy_to/releases' folder. And re-do a symlink to the previous releases folder from the current folder. This is yet to be verified though.

Comment: Sounds the way chef deploy resource work, as far as I know the behavior is mimicking Capistrano with a release dir containing the releases and a current simlink pointing the release to use... I'll try to dig on it if needed tomorow

Comment: @Tensibai   Yes, chef does admits that 'deploy' is designed to work similar to Capistrano.  But it seems to keep a track of the revisions deployed via a file. This is a paste from the chef-docs. The chef-client uses a cache file to keep track of the order in which each revision of an application is deployed. By default, the cache file is located at /var/chef/cache/revision-deploys/APPNAME/. To force a re-deploy, delete the deployment directory or delete the cache file.

Comment: Indeed, but this part is chef specific and I have no clue about how Capistrano keep previous version. I'm afraid we're stepping off topic for stack overflow but I've no clues to give,  I'll try an ext need search tomorow if I find time (at home now, it's 9:40 pm and I'ce dishes to wash ;))